# Joining two tables where date in second table should be first date after date in first table i.e earliest date after date in first table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Problem statement description :-
I have two tables - table1 and table2 . table1 contains data of  quantity buy of id=7 and table2 contain data of quantity sold of same id=7. Both table1 and table2 is sorted according to date i.e from oldest to latest date and every time only 1 quantity is buy or sold.

table1:

| table1 |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| date_buy | id | qty_buy | rolling_sum_qty_buy |
| 30-07-2019 | 7 | 1 | 1 |
| 20-10-2019 | 7 | 1 | 2 |
| 17-01-2020 | 7 | 1 | 3 |
| 15-02-2020 | 7 | 1 | 4 |
| 15-02-2020 | 7 | 1 | 5 |
| 15-02-2020 | 7 | 1 | 6 |
| 14-07-2021 | 7 | 1 | 7 |
| 19-09-2021 | 7 | 1 | 8 |
| 25-12-2021 | 7 | 1 | 9 |
| 30-12-2021 | 7 | 1 | 10 |
| 10-02-2022 | 7 | 1 | 11 |
| 15-03-2022 | 7 | 1 | 12 |
| 15-03-2022 | 7 | 1 | 13 |
| 14-06-2022 | 7 | 1 | 14 |

table2:-

| table2 |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| date_sold | id | qty_sold | rolling_sum_qty_sold |
| 01-08-2019 | 7 | 1 | 1 |
| 15-09-2019 | 7 | 1 | 2 |
| 27-12-2019 | 7 | 1 | 3 |
| 01-02-2020 | 7 | 1 | 4 |
| 12-02-2020 | 7 | 1 | 5 |
| 25-07-2021 | 7 | 1 | 6 |
| 25-07-2021 | 7 | 1 | 7 |
| 28-08-2021 | 7 | 1 | 8 |
| 10-09-2021 | 7 | 1 | 9 |
| 12-09-2021 | 7 | 1 | 10 |
| 25-04-2022 | 7 | 1 | 11 |

-- SQL scrtpt of table1:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (
    `date_buy` DATETIME,
    `id` INT,
    `qty_buy` INT,
    `rolling_sum_qty_buy` INT
);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
    ('2019-07-30 00:00:00',7,1,1),
    ('2019-10-20 00:00:00',7,1,2),
    ('2020-01-17 00:00:00',7,1,3),
    ('2020-02-15 00:00:00',7,1,4),
    ('2020-02-15 00:00:00',7,1,5),
    ('2020-02-15 00:00:00',7,1,6),
    ('2021-07-14 00:00:00',7,1,7),
    ('2021-09-19 00:00:00',7,1,8),
    ('2021-12-25 00:00:00',7,1,9),
    ('2021-12-30 00:00:00',7,1,10),
    ('2022-02-10 00:00:00',7,1,11),
    ('2022-03-15 00:00:00',7,1,12),
    ('2022-03-15 00:00:00',7,1,13),
    ('2022-06-14 00:00:00',7,1,14);

-- sql script of table2:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 (
    `date_sold` DATETIME,
    `id` INT,
    `qty_sold` INT,
    `rolling_sum_qty_sold` INT
);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES
    ('2019-08-01 00:00:00',7,1,1),
    ('2019-09-15 00:00:00',7,1,2),
    ('2019-12-27 00:00:00',7,1,3),
    ('2020-02-01 00:00:00',7,1,4),
    ('2020-02-12 00:00:00',7,1,5),
    ('2021-07-25 00:00:00',7,1,6),
    ('2021-07-25 00:00:00',7,1,7),
    ('2021-08-28 00:00:00',7,1,8),
    ('2021-09-10 00:00:00',7,1,9),
    ('2021-09-12 00:00:00',7,1,10),
    ('2022-04-25 00:00:00',7,1,11);
```

-- Now, i want to join this two table on two condition

1. for every date i.e date_buy column in table1 i should get output where date i.e date_sold is greater than date_buy and i want first date i.e. date_sold which is greater than that particular date i.e date_buy.
2. i also want those rows from table1 in my output which does not get joined with table2
   so that i can easily find out the remaining quantity because in table1 i have quantity buy and after joining with table2 i will get quantity sold, so the cases where i get null values then in that case i can assume that that much quantity is remaining.

--My output:-
Earlier when there was no date issue then i was simply using left join to join table1 and table2 on rolling sum condition and where there was null cases i was taking sum of qty to get remaining qty but right now i have that condition too so i cant use rolling_sum_cond column directly in join condition.

-- query which i was using and output which i was getting earlier

```
select * from table1
left join table2 
on table1.rolling_sum_qty_buy=table2.rolling_sum_qty_sold
```

| date_buy | id | qty_buy | rolling_sum_qty_buy | date_sold | id-2 | qty_sold | rolling_sum_qty_sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30-07-2019 | 7 | 1 | 1 | 01-08-2019 | 7 | 1 | 1 |
| 20-10-2019 | 7 | 1 | 2 | 15-09-2019 | 7 | 1 | 2 |
| 17-01-2020 | 7 | 1 | 3 | 27-12-2019 | 7 | 1 | 3 |
| 15-02-2020 | 7 | 1 | 4 | 01-02-2020 | 7 | 1 | 4 |
| 15-02-2020 | 7 | 1 | 5 | 12-02-2020 | 7 | 1 | 5 |
| 15-02-2020 | 7 | 1 | 6 | 25-07-2021 | 7 | 1 | 6 |
| 14-07-2021 | 7 | 1 | 7 | 25-07-2021 | 7 | 1 | 7 |
| 19-09-2021 | 7 | 1 | 8 | 28-08-2021 | 7 | 1 | 8 |
| 25-12-2021 | 7 | 1 | 9 | 10-09-2021 | 7 | 1 | 9 |
| 30-12-2021 | 7 | 1 | 10 | 12-09-2021 | 7 | 1 | 10 |
| 10-02-2022 | 7 | 1 | 11 | 25-04-2022 | 7 | 1 | 11 |
| 15-03-2022 | 7 | 1 | 12 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 15-03-2022 | 7 | 1 | 13 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 14-06-2022 | 7 | 1 | 14 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

and to find out remaining quantity , i was using null condition
query:-

```
 with cte as 
(
select * from table1
left join table2 
on table1.rolling_sum_qty_buy=table2.rolling_sum_qty_sold
)
select sum(qty_buy) as remaining_qty 
from cte
where cte.date_sold is null
```

| remaining_qty |
| --- |
| 3 |

-- my expectation
now i have to use date condition also to get the output

-- **Expected Output**

| date_buy | id | qty_buy | rolling_sum_qty_buy | date_sold | id | qty_sold | rolling_sum_qty_sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30-07-2019 | 7 | 1 | 1 | 01-08-2019 | 7 | 1 | 1 |
| 20-10-2019 | 7 | 1 | 2 | 27-12-2019 | 7 | 1 | 3 |
| 17-01-2020 | 7 | 1 | 3 | 01-02-2020 | 7 | 1 | 4 |
| 15-02-2020 | 7 | 1 | 4 | 25-07-2021 | 7 | 1 | 6 |
| 15-02-2020 | 7 | 1 | 5 | 25-07-2021 | 7 | 1 | 7 |
| 15-02-2020 | 7 | 1 | 6 | 28-08-2021 | 7 | 1 | 8 |
| 14-07-2021 | 7 | 1 | 7 | 10-09-2021 | 7 | 1 | 9 |
| 19-09-2021 | 7 | 1 | 8 | 25-04-2022 | 7 | 1 | 11 |
| 25-12-2021 | 7 | 1 | 9 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 30-12-2021 | 7 | 1 | 10 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 10-02-2022 | 7 | 1 | 11 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 15-03-2022 | 7 | 1 | 12 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 15-03-2022 | 7 | 1 | 13 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 14-06-2022 | 7 | 1 | 14 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

-- Please help me to get the following output. Any help would be appreciated.
I am using postgresql.

Comment: are you sure that you are using postgres, the code provided suggest mysql

Comment: I think you must rethink your strategy, because applying your logic leeds to https://dbfiddle.uk/wBIeO-Mn

Comment: Actually i am using dbeaver which supports almost postgresql, actually the data was so large , thats why i converted some data to sql script via online editor, thats why the code seems to be of mysql. @nbk

Comment: Actually, what i want is- for every table1 row i want to utilise 1 quantity of table2 i.e join 1 1 row from to table 1 with 1 row of table2 and this join should only takes place when the date condition matches i.e for every date_buy  , date_sold should be greater than date_buy.

Comment: You @nbk can refer my expected output table. So, the major problem which i was facing here is i have only 1 joining condition i.e, rolling_sum_qty_buy and corresponding rolling_sum_qty_sold but this condition doesn;t holds true when date scenario is coming in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a challenging one.

```
with recursive cte as
(
  select   t2.date_sold
          ,t2.rolling_sum_qty_sold
          ,true as is_match
          ,1 as last_rolling_sum_qty_buy                           
  from     t2 join t on t2.rolling_sum_qty_sold = t.rolling_sum_qty_buy
  where    t2.rolling_sum_qty_sold = 1 
        
   
  union all 
  
  select t2.date_sold
        ,t2.rolling_sum_qty_sold 
        ,t2.date_sold >= t.date_buy
        ,cte.last_rolling_sum_qty_buy + case when t2.date_sold >= t.date_buy then 1 else 0 end
  from   t2 
         join cte on cte.rolling_sum_qty_sold + 1 = t2.rolling_sum_qty_sold
         join t   on t.rolling_sum_qty_buy = cte.last_rolling_sum_qty_buy + 1
          
)

select  t.date_buy  
       ,t.id    
       ,t.qty_buy   
       ,t.rolling_sum_qty_buy   
       ,cte.date_sold   
       ,cte.rolling_sum_qty_sold
from    t left join cte on cte.last_rolling_sum_qty_buy = t.rolling_sum_qty_buy and is_match
```

| date_buy | id | qty_buy | rolling_sum_qty_buy | date_sold | rolling_sum_qty_sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-07-30 | 7 | 1 | 1 | 2019-08-01 | 1 |
| 2019-10-20 | 7 | 1 | 2 | 2019-12-27 | 3 |
| 2020-01-17 | 7 | 1 | 3 | 2020-02-01 | 4 |
| 2020-02-15 | 7 | 1 | 4 | 2021-07-25 | 6 |
| 2020-02-15 | 7 | 1 | 5 | 2021-07-25 | 7 |
| 2020-02-15 | 7 | 1 | 6 | 2021-08-28 | 8 |
| 2021-07-14 | 7 | 1 | 7 | 2021-09-10 | 9 |
| 2021-09-19 | 7 | 1 | 8 | 2022-04-25 | 11 |
| 2021-12-25 | 7 | 1 | 9 | null | null |
| 2021-12-30 | 7 | 1 | 10 | null | null |
| 2022-02-10 | 7 | 1 | 11 | null | null |
| 2022-03-15 | 7 | 1 | 12 | null | null |
| 2022-03-15 | 7 | 1 | 13 | null | null |
| 2022-06-14 | 7 | 1 | 14 | null | null |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fXOZzcXA)

Comment: I am getting one corner case error in the above provided solution. For example , in the above solution we are assuming that the 1st date of table2 ,i.e date_sold='01-08-2019' is always greater 1st date_buy of table1 i.e '30-07-2019' because it is our first query or non-recursive part of recursive cte but if the 1st date_sold of table2 is <= 1st date_buy of table1 then this query will not holds true. For ex : if we replace 1st date_sold  i.e '01-08-2019' by '01-08-2018' then above query will fail here for 1st row. @DannySlor

Comment: How can you sell something you don't have yet? That's why I put it in like that. Its a lot to explain. It would be best for you to start playing with the fiddle and taking it apart.